# How to fill a text box with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to fill a text box with my student code 21314423, but when I execute it it throws me this:

```
DeprecationWarning: use driver.switch_to.frame instead driver.switch_to_frame (driver.find_element_by_xpath ("// frame [@ name = 'Menu']")
```

This is all code the HTML:

This is the code that I use:

```py
But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?
```

Comment: or can you do this instead `Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> then right click on the element you want to share the outer HTML - > select copy and then outer HTML`, it's hard to read from pictures.

Comment: That is the problem, the html is fragmented into two parts. When inspecting the `pcodigo` element, it doesn't show me the html, I have to do it in another section of the code and then find the element I want.

Comment: Can you let us know the test credentials as well ? may be a temporary one ?

Comment: I would like to be able to share the credentials to make it faster, but within our accounts we can associate our cards to make payments (It are literally in plain text). The html is in the images that I added in imgur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below should work for you to switch to **frame** :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "contenido")))
print('yes ! Switched to frame ')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "pCodigoAlumno"))).send_keys('21314423')
print("Number was sent successfully")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I do not know why, but the page as I mentioned is fragmented in two parts, your code is correct, it was only necessary to add the `mainframe` again